# Laravel 405 method not allowed in live hosting

Tags: php, linux, laravel, file-upload, web-hosting

Since a lot of days I am trying to upload file in the server I got 405 methods not allowed error in live server:
This is my view:
HTML & javascript

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
form id="uploaddiamond" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Upload Diamond <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input required="" type="file" name="result_file" id="result_file" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection()
@section('javascript')
<script>
$("#uploaddiamond").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('tst');
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var file_data = $('#result_file').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('diamond') }}", // point to server-side PHP script
            data: form_data,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
});
</script>
@endsection()

This is my web route:
Route::get('/imageview','ImageController@index')->name('getimage');
Route::post('/postDiamond','ImageController@postDiamond')->name('diamond');
```

```
This is my controller:
```

```
 public function index(){
        return view('Image/imgupload');
    }


    public function postDiamond(Request $request){
    dd($request->file('file'));
        $supplier_name = $request->supplier_name;
        $extension = $request->file('file');
        $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting excel extension
        $dir = 'assets/files/';
        $filename = uniqid().'_'.time().'_'.date('Ymd').'.'.$extension;
        $request->file('file')->move($dir, $filename);
    }
```

I don't why this code is not working cause this code works in localhost but, not working in Linux hosting:
Can someone help do I have did a mistake on version something
server current PHP version:7.3.17
laravel PHP version:7.1.10

This is my server error image please check:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niApG.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1L0B.jpg)

Comment: have you included csrf token in meta tag as well ? globally ?

Comment: yes, sir, I have named _token

Comment: try to change this order and check `url: "{{ route('diamond') }}", data: form_data,type: 'POST',` TO `type: 'POST', url: "{{ route('diamond') }}", data: form_data`

Comment: Can you show the routing map? by default in routes/web.php
However if you have laravel 7, require php version >= 7.2.5
But i suspect a wrong method like the error say

Comment: Nothing Works sir

Comment: sir Laravel version 5.8.* & routes provided above in code section below view @sergio

Comment: I have just tested my own code and it works fine on localhost as well as live server. I am sharing my code with you.

Answer (score 0):

> Well I have just tested this code on live server and it's working fine. If this code still doesn't work for you then you need to check permissions on server side for some files like `web.php` etc...

```
$(document).on('click','#submit_button', function(e){ //#submit_button id on submit button
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this.form);

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    }
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '{{ route("diamond") }}',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,

    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

*Be sure to remove @csrf from your `<form>` tag.* 
*In controller just `dd(request()->all());` and see what you get*

Comment: Well clear your cache on server side `php artisan route:clear` , `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: tried sir,  your code worked for localhost but, not in the server still not working your code is perfect but, I have doubt on my server and I'm not expert in the server can you please tell me some solution

Comment: web.php permission is 755, and Route::get('/clear', function() {
    
        Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        Artisan::call('config:clear');
        Artisan::call('config:cache');
        Artisan::call('view:clear');
        Artisan::call('route:clear');
     
        return "Cleared!";
     
}); and using this route in server to clear

Comment: If it is still not working, please give a few minutes to this link and read it. it might help you, especially focus on Server Side Configuration in this site. https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/405-method-not-allowed

Comment: ```DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

</IfModule>``` sir this is my .htaccess conf please verify it's right? still reading you provided post

Comment: Can you help me with ModSec issue on server side I read on some post that there might be ModSec issues

Comment: There might be but i would suggest you to watch a simple tutorial on `.htaccess` you will learn many things